# Migration to Berkshelf

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo, berkshelf

I am currently in the process of migrating our organization's `kitchen` to `Berkshelf`.

**SETUP**

We use `git submodules` to maintain the `vendor cookbooks` in the `cookbooks` dir. our `custom cookbooks` are in `site-cookbooks`.

I got rid of all the `submodules` in `cookbooks` dir and created a `Berksfile` with our custom cookbooks. I have set `ENV['BERKSHELF_PATH']` in `Berksfile` to `cookbooks` dir so as to contain the vendor cookbooks in one place and added cookbooks dir to `.gitignore`.

When I execute `Berks install` the vendor cookbooks are installed in cookbooks dir as `cookbook_name`-`version`.

**PROBLEM**

When I run `chef-solo` to run the custom cookbooks, chef run fails as the recipes in vendor cookbooks which have either `template` resource or `cookbook_file` resource fail as chef is unable to find the templates or files in `files` dir or `templates` dir of the cookbook even though they are present.

Renaming the vendor cookbooks from say `apt-2.7.0` as installed by `berkshelf` to just `apt` without the `version number` and adding the vendor cookbook to Berksfile as for example `cookbook 'apt', path: './cookbooks/apt'` solves the problem.

However I honestly think that I am heading in the wrong direction and this should not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to set `BERKSHELF_PATH`, that is the internal tracking directory for Berkshelf and should almost never be touched. Kitchen will automatically handle running `berks vendor` for you as part of the provisioning process.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes. It did work. I was setting the berkshelf's install path to cookbooks and using it to run the in-house cookbooks. I unset the berkshelf path and `berks vendor` did the trick!